# Checking uniform convergence of $\sum\frac{\left(x\ln x\right)^{n}}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

> Find the set where the series $\sum\frac{\left(x\ln x\right)^{n}}{n}$
>   converges and determine if convergence is uniform on that set.

I used root test to find the set of convergence:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{\left(x\ln x\right)^{n}}{n}}<1\Rightarrow\frac{x\ln x}{1}<1\Rightarrow\ln x^{x}<1\Rightarrow x^{x}<e$$

1. How to understand what kind of set this is it without using soft like Mathematica or Sage? I see that 0 and 1 satisfies this inequality.

Using $\ln|1+x|=\sum\left(-1\right)^{n}\frac{y^{n}}{n}$, I got the sum of that series

$$\sum\frac{\left(x\ln x\right)^{n}}{n}=-\ln|1-x\ln x|$$

2. How to determine if the convergence to that function uniform or not?

Answer (score 1):

Sketch: The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}u^n/n$ converges iff $u\in[-1,1).$ Thus $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(x\ln x)^n/n$ converges iff $-1\le x\ln x < 1.$ This is true iff $x\in (0,a),$ where $a$ is the unique $x$ such that $x\ln x =1.$ You can see $1<a<2,$ but I don't know its exact value. As for uniform convergence, we'll have that on $(0,r)$ for each $r,$ $0<r <a.$